# GHC 7.10.2 warning when deriving Unbox instance using Data.Vector.Unboxed.Deriving

Tags: haskell, vector, template-haskell, unboxing

The following program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, RankNTypes, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Vector.Unboxed
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Deriving
import Data.Word

data Pixel a = Pixel a deriving Show

derivingUnbox "Pixel"
    [t| forall a . (Unbox a) => Pixel a -> a |]
    [| \ (Pixel a) -> a |]
    [| \ a -> (Pixel a) |]

main = print $ Pixel 0
```

Uses template haskell to derive an Unbox instance for Pixel. It worked on GHC 7.8, but on 7.10.2, I get the following warning:

```
/Users/v/haskell/Tests/pix.hs:11:1: Warning:
    No explicit implementation for
      ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.Base.basicInitialize’
    In the instance declaration for
      ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.Base.MVector MVector (Pixel a_a6Ue)’
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vector-th-unboxed` package that provides the template you're using has not been updated since `basicInitialize` was added to the `Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.Base.MVector` class. <strike>You should [file an issue](https://github.com/liyang/vector-th-unbox/issues) to get the macro fixed, and you may wish to</strike> You should contact a [Hackage trustee](https://www.haskell.org/wiki/Hackage%20trustees) to see about getting the dependency bounds for `vector-th-unbox` adjusted in the mean time. Code written for recent versions of `vector` is likely to use `basicInitialize` (directly or indirectly); when that function is called with a `Point`, it will throw a runtime error.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/liyang/vector-th-unbox/pull/10) open to fix this issue, but the maintainer has not accepted it. You may wish to review it yourself and apply it locally.

Comment: Good catch, thank you! Why did you remove the `compiler-errors` tag?

Comment: @Viclib, it's pretty hard to see how it will help someone find the question, decide whether they are interested in/knowledgeable about the question, etc. Frankly, the tag probably shouldn't exist.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm not sure I understood how I should report the issue to Hackage trustees. Should I just open an issue on the tracker? If that is the case, it is done. Thank you again.

Comment: @Viclib, yup! I didn't even know that tracker existed till just now :-P

Comment: Apologies, I've been ‘travelling’ and hiding from the interwebs and generally shirking my responsibilities. Pushed the fixes and will tag and upload to Hackage as soon as Travis gives me the go-ahead.